# Можно ли каким-либо образом пересохранить базу данных в кодировке windows-1251 в базу данных utf-8 на SQL Server 19?

Tags: php, sql-server

У меня база из ssms_14 перекочевала в ssms_19(ms sql server 2022). PHP подключается к MS SQL server через odbc . В браузере выводятся знаки вопросов  вместо кириллицы. В браузере по умолчанию кодировка utf-8. Если в Charset (extention) выставляешь Cyrillic(Windows 1251), то появляется кириллица. Проблему перекодировки можно решить поредством функции  iconv. Можно ли проблему в корне решить, каким-либо образом пересохранив базу данных(windows-1251) в базу данных(utf-8) на SQL Server 19(поддерживает utf-8)?

Comment: SSMS - это **не** база данных. Это графический интерфейс для работы с БД.

Comment: не в тему, но есть pdo и sqlsrv, на кой odbc ?